# api integration php curl

Tags: php, api, curl, http-headers

I am trying to integrate an API, and in the API integration instructions it shows the following:

```
GET /offers.json or /offers.xml
Headers: API-KEY={your_key}, API-LOGIN={your_login}
```

**CURL Example:**

```
curl https://api.thewebsite.com/v1/offers.json -H 'API-KEY:
1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i' -H 'API-LOGIN: 1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i'
```

I've tried using the cURL code below without success. As for the GET method, I'm not sure how to pass the API KEY & API LOGIN as headers.

```
$header = array('Content-Type: application/xml', 'API-KEY=1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i', 'API-LOGIN=1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i');
$url = "https://api.thewebsite.com/v1/offers.xml";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$xml = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

print $xml;
```

Comment: What happens when you execute that curl script?

Comment: I was getting a Invalid API key error, which would be due to the use of = rather than : as Kaivosukeltaja pointed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP headers need to be specified using a colon as the separator between the key and the value, not an equal sign. Try this:

```
$header = array('Content-Type: application/xml', 'API-KEY: 1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i', 'API-LOGIN: 1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i');
```

Comment: (doh) I had used the = trying something else and forgot to change it. Thanks!

Comment: I've been trying to only print the details of the first offer returned. However the entire XML is displayed. Even if I remove all print calls.
`## begin snip ##
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <offers type="array">
    <offer>
      <end-date type="datetime">2011-09-22T23:59:59Z</end-date>
      <details>First offer details here</details>
      <faq nil="true"></faq>
      <value type="float">495.0</value>
## end snip ##

print $xml->offer[0]->details`

Answer (score 0):

You can get some debug information from curl, and see exactly what doesn't work for you:

```
print "<pre>\n";
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));  // get error info
echo "\n\ncURL error number:" .curl_errno($curl); // print error info
echo "\n\ncURL error:" . curl_error($ch); 
print "</pre>\n";
curl_close($curl); // close curl session
```

Make sure to call it before you close and terminate the curl object

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep it handy for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

```
print "<pre>\n";
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));  // get error info
echo "\n\ncURL error number:" .curl_errno($curl); // print error info
echo "\n\ncURL error:" . curl_error($ch); 
print "</pre>\n";
curl_close($curl);
```